# Is this query being executed on an in-memory collection, or in the database?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity framework on a forum website and have two query examples with questions.

Query #1) This query is supposed to get a topic count of all topics in the forum. Is it executing a count in SQL so that I only get a number back? Or is it pulling all the topics into memory and then counting the topics in the collection?

```
            return DBContext.Topics
                .Where(x => !x.ModsOnly)
                .Where(x => !x.Board.ModsOnly)
                .Where(x => !x.Board.Hidden)
                .Count();
```

Query #2) This query is supposed to get all topics, order them by last reply date (or topic date if no replies). Then it counts the results, and pages the results. How much of this query is executed in the database? This query takes FOREVER so I think it is pulling all topics into memory at some point, likely before the paging takes affect.

```
            var query = DBContext.Topics
                    .Where(x => !x.ModsOnly)
                    .Where(x => !x.Board.ModsOnly)
                    .Where(x => !x.Board.Hidden)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.GlobalSticky)
                    .ThenByDescending(x => x.Replies
                        .Where(r => !r.ModsOnly)
                        .Any() ? x.Replies
                            .Where(r => !r.ModsOnly)
                            .Max(r => r.PostedDate) : x.PostedDate);
                int totalTopics = query.Count();
                if (totalTopics > itemsPerPage)
                    return query.Skip((page - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage);
                else
                    return query;
```

I am not a LINQ guru. This is a complicated query I know. Where did I go wrong?

Note: I am trying to avoid creating a column in topics called "LastReplyDate" and ordering topics by that. For my purposes I would like the ordering to be by the last reply, and not by an arbitrary column on topic that I could have to update with every added/deleted reply.

However, if readers think there is no other way to accomplish my goal, I will consider that route.

Comment: @Chevex isn't easier to attach the sqlprofiler to examine the performance and behavior of queries?

Comment: @marc Hmmm, I did not know I could do that. Is that a method on the EF context object? @rene, I suppose, mind posting an answer with an example of how to accomplish that?

Comment: To be fair, it is much easier in linq-to-SQL (just ctx.Log = Console.Out) - with EF the SQL profiler tool, or Ayende's profiler maybe

Comment: @Chevex if you're using SQL Server, SSMS has a `SQL Server Profiler` tool that you can set up to trace RPCs on your database.

Comment: Okay well I will look into a profiler. In the meantime if any LINQ guru's mind looking at my queries, it would be tremendously helpful. I am not confident in them at all as I am new to LINQ altogether.

Comment: Still another option is to use LINQPad, which understands your EF model and will give you a SQL trace.

Comment: It would appear that I need to have more privileges in SQL server to do the profiler. The DB I am using is not controlled by me and I do not have permission to do this.

Comment: Craig, I just tried out linq pad. It hooked right into my EF model and I'm able to paste my queries in there. It's great stuff! I am indeed able to confirm that all operations in this query are being done in the database. And to my dismay, it wasn't very slow. My server must be under strain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example will use one DB query. Yes, it does the count in SQL.

Your second will use two. One for the `int totalTopics = query.Count();` and one for the paged results.

Neither one of them will do the restriction, etc., in memory.

Comment: Hmmm, could the query be taking so long then because of the way it orders the topics by querying its replies' dates?

Comment: Thank you for answering my original question. This doesn't help my problem, but does indeed answer the question. Thanks much! +1

Comment: The queries could take a long time for many reasons. Perhaps the DB query is slow. Perhaps the EF overhead is high. Perhaps they are unnecessarily complex. As others have mentioned, you need to profile this.

Comment: Yeah, I can't profile it. I don't have the right permissions on the database. However I did use LINQpad as you suggested and not only were the queries being executed int he database correctly, but they were both really fast. I'm sure I have some other issues going on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The queries will be executed on the database, but for the second one I would recommend taking out the order by clauses since they are not necessary for the count operation and are slowing it down.

Comment: Okay, easy enough, but the query is still slow even if it has the count from the first count query before it even executes the second query.

Comment: @Chevex are you saying that your Query #1) is slow?

Comment: No, query 1 is lightning fast. Query 2 is slow. I'm just saying that query 2 is still dirt slow, even with the order by clauses removed.